# How to add another method to the onlick event of the Pinterest's button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, pinterest

pinit.js replaces specially-marked anchor tags with IFRAMEs.

I want to add an alert message when the user clicks the Pinterest button before it actually asks me to login. Is that possible?

Here is the code: http://jsfiddle.net/ucuHY/14/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible. Unless, someone replies that this is indeed possible. I will take this answer